# Why do the Walnuts of Our Trees Get Black and Could Not Ripe

Tags: diseases, pests, walnut

We have a cottage in a very close proximity to the Black Sea (around 2 kilometers) in what is referred to as a Temperate Climate Zone environment. We have 3 old walnut trees that give a fair amount of walnuts each year. However, most of them get black and fall out from the tree prematurely. According to my grandmother, in the past, there was no such problem with the walnuts. However, with each year, more and more nuts get spoiled.
The trees are very huge and it would be very hard to spray them with bordeaux spray or anything else. Has anyone else experienced such problem with walnut trees and are there some more "natural" ways to handle this?

Comment: pictures please!

Comment: When you say that the nuts are black, do you mean the outer skins, the nuts inside the skins, or both? Are there any small white worms inside the nuts?

Comment: @Jurp, during summertime the outer green shell starts getting black and in most cases it also spoils the nut inside. So, by the time the nut should be ready, the green shell becomes fully black and dries out around the nut. When you crack it open, the nut inside is rancid and inedible (or in some rare cases it is fully missing).